# Set Sharepoint Tags/Properies with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

Is it possible to set the Tags of a Sharepoint document (specifically Excel) using VBA. At present the only way I know to handle this is to save a file to Sharepoint, set the Tags when prompted, nd then download this file again and use it as a template.

However, I need to work with several different permuations of these Tags and it's a major pain having to create a separate template for each one, especially if you then need to amend the template, and have to replicate those amendments 10s of times.

So is it possible to do this via VBA? I've tried recording a macro whilst I set them and it doesn't record anything regarding the Tags

Comment: What Version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Hi - I'm using Sharepoint 2013

Comment: How fluent are you in code? Do you understand rest webservices? Or do you just want some VBA function that handles all of it for you?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rest, am OK with C# but for this task really need VBA if possible. If VBA isn't feasible then it would be good to know what the alternatives are, as otherwise I'm going to be faced with managing literally hundreds of identical templates, with only the Sharepoint tags being different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know , we can set the Tags of an **Excel document** in **VBA** before it gets uploaded onto a Sharepoint library, 
by settings values for the

```
Workbook.ContentTypeProperties
```

For example:

```vba
 ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Line of Business").Value = pLine
 ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Company Name").Value = pCompany
 ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Year").Value = pYear
```

I'd link some readings to learn more: It might be useful:[John Chapman's SharePoint Blog: Update SharePoint Document Property from Excel VBA]

http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2007-–-update-sharepoint-document-property-from-excel-vba/

Please note that there are some troubles with certain types of property: see 
[Setting Custom Document properties that will be used in Sharepoint](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/729940-setting-custom-document-properties-will-used-sharepoint.html) and [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6adcd4dd-4cf1-4990-9e8c-932bdf478a27/how-to-addupdate-user-type-of-document-properties-of-a-sharepoint-document-in-office-ui?forum=exceldev)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can confirm that I am able to set the Sharepoint tags using this method, however the document needs to have been saved to Sharepoint first in order to know what the tags are. This does help a lot, though it would be good to be able to set the Tags in advance of the upload to Sharepoint if possible, so I'm going to leave the bounty open for a few more days in case anyone does know a method of doing this, although it doesn't seem that there is a way

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The workaround I used was as follows

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Pth
ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Report Type").Value = "BranchManagement"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Pth
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).CheckIn
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0
```

In my case I also had to check the book in after getting it saved. Hope this helps!